# Pymongo Not creating collection in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is the simple piece of code to create collection.But collection is not created.

```
import pymongo

conn=pymongo.Connection()
db=conn["userdb"]
table=db["Books"]
```

COuld anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The collection will not be created until you add data, this is since collections and even databases in MongoDB are done lazily by default.

If you wish to explicitly allocate a collection eagerly then use `db.create_collection(name)`: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection